# Add Rows below row 1, Fill first cell with docvariable and increment

Tags: vba, ms-word

Solved my own problem.  I needed to first check if column 2 cells were empty and if so delete said row.  This caused issues due to last row of table being merged across.  I then needed to add rows below first row, to maintain 4 columns in each row, in table based on user selection of ArraySize in userform.  Then populate first cell in each row with a docvariable in userform followed by incrementing number in each row.  Then sort table in descending order.  Here is my code for future use.

```
Private Sub cbArraySize_Click()

If cbArraySize.Value <> 0 Then

DeleteRows
AddRows
AddArrayName
TableSort

End If

End Sub

Sub DeleteRows()

Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim nrRows As Long, ColToCheck As Long, i As Long
    Dim cellRange As Word.Range

    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
    nrRows = tbl.Rows.Count - 1
    ColToCheck = 2

    For i = nrRows To 1 Step -1
        Set cellRange = tbl.Cell(i, ColToCheck).Range
        If Len(cellRange.Text) = 2 Then
            cellRange.Rows(1).Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub AddRows()
With ActiveDocument

.Tables(2).Rows(1).Select
Selection.InsertRowsBelow (cbArraySize.Value)

End With
End Sub

Sub AddArrayName()
With ActiveDocument

Dim tbl As Object
Dim noOfCol As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim intcount As Integer

Set tbl = .Tables(2)
        With tbl
            noOfCol = tbl.Range.Rows(1).Cells.Count
            For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
                With .Rows(i)
                    If Len(.Range) = noOfCol * 2 + 2 Then .Cells(1).Range.InsertAfter Text:=tbArrayName.Text + " - " & intcount
                intcount = intcount + 1
                End With
            Next i
End With
End With
End Sub

Sub TableSort()
ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Sort ExcludeHeader:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: The description of what should be happening isn't clear. A screen shot or two might help with that. I also recommend you add code to `ÀddArrayName` that does as much as you're able to work out of what you want then explain what it still isn't doing. In other words, this question needs to be more precise.

Comment: Thanks Cindy, I added an example table.  I would add code to AddArrayName but I not sure how to loop through the first cell of each row to add to it.

Comment: At least include the code that adds the DocVariable and some text. Then we can show you how to build a loop around it.

Comment: Tip: In order to make sure a reply in comments appears in a person's inbox be sure to "ping" them explicitly using @: @VBAWannaBe for example. As the person asking the question, you'll automatically get a notification for all comments, but the reverse isn't true :-)

Comment: @CindyMeister Hello Cindy, I have updated my code with GMalcs input and have some more learning to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted my working code in original post.